# Simplify .Include and .ThenInclude calls in Entity Framework Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core 6.0 in my project
I have the following code structure:

```cs
public class Game
{
    public Team Team1 { get; set; }
    public Team Team2 { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Team
{
    public Player Player1 { get; set; }
    public Race Race1 { get; set; }
    public Player Player2 { get; set; }
    public Race Race2 { get; set; }
}
```

(other fields omitted for simplicity)

I want to load all the data about all the games, so in my service class I do:

```cs
        var games = await _context.Games
            .Include(g => g.Team1)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Player1)
            .Include(g => g.Team1)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Race1)
            .Include(g => g.Team1)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Player2)
            .Include(g => g.Team1)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Race2)
            .Include(g => g.Team2)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Player1)
            .Include(g => g.Team2)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Race1)
            .Include(g => g.Team2)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Player2)
            .Include(g => g.Team2)
                .ThenInclude(t => t.Race2)
            .ToArrayAsync();

//Collect the statistics
```

However, it looks ugly and takes up a lot of lines.
Is there a way to simplify this code?

P.S. I don't want to use Lazy Loading for the whole context, so it is not an option here.

Comment: Please say me the relationships between tables.(one-one or many-many or one-many)

Comment: The game has two teams, each team has two players and two races. So it is 1 to many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify including of non-collection navigation properties:

```cs
var games = await _context.Games
    .Include(g => g.Team1.Player1)
    .Include(g => g.Team1.Race1)
    .Include(g => g.Team1.Player2)
    .Include(g => g.Team1.Race2)
    .Include(g => g.Team2.Player1)
    .Include(g => g.Team2.Race1)
    .Include(g => g.Team2.Player2)
    .Include(g => g.Team2.Race2)
    .ToArrayAsync();
```